# Log into Ubuntu from my Mac over VNC

Tags: screen, mac, vnc, macosx, sharing

Using SSL/SSH Viewer and tapping in the IP address, I can fully screen share my Mac Mini which is upstairs, in fact, I'm writing this question right now in the OS X environment on my laptop screen running Ubuntu 12.04. Easy.

However I cannot log into Ubuntu from the Mac -> Go -> Connect to Server, tap in the IP address of the Ubuntu Laptop. I have enabled "Allow others to control your Desktop" in Desktop Sharing. I have also installed a VNC App called Chicken of the VNC and disabled Bonjour - it times out or tells me to enable Sharing.

Surely it cannot be that difficult to just connect to Ubuntu?

I've read some documentation about VNC and it goes on about using VNC and the opening line states:

"Although VNC has some optional security features, you should not run VNC directly over an untrusted network like the Internet. Instead, you should set an SSH server up as discussed in the SSH guide and configure a VNC server that you can start in so-called once mode."

i.e. it says absolutely nothing about VNC and instead sends you on a never-ending trail of SSH Servers, port forwarding and RSA Keys. About how Derek wants to log into his Windows machine at work.

I want to plug in an ethernet cable into both machines and screen share via VNC.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

PS

OK just to add something. I can actually see the Ubuntu laptop, and it gives me the IP address, but cannot connect. Interestingly, I can actually log into the Ubuntu screen from the Ubuntu laptop! Using the SSL/SSH Viewer in Ubuntu it logs into itself (the screen reloads itself within itself) but it works, but not when trying it on the Mac.

Comment: Do you really really need a vnc? if not use http://www.teamviewer.com/ and get it done in 1 minute

Comment: See this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/460716/vnc-mac-to-ubuntu-on-trusted-network

Comment: See answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/463486/can-no-longer-use-screen-share-to-connect-mac-to-ubuntu-since-upgrading-to-14-04

Answer (score 3):

you need to use port after your ip address eg 192.168.2.5:5900 also some clients require two colens after the ip then it'll be something like 192.168.2.5::5900

Comment: and also which vnc server are you using in ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. On your mac, first create an SSH tunnel to the Ubuntu machine:

`ssh -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 -N -f -l <your-linux-user-name> <linux-ip>`

Here is an example:

`ssh -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 -N -f -l inder 192.168.50.73`

Step 2. On your mac, connect to linux using Screen Sharing using VNC
Press Command-Space, type "Screen Sharing". Start Screen Sharing app.
type: 

`vnc://127.0.0.1:5900`

You are in the VNC session.

Comment: +1 for vnc://127.0.0.1:5900

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a port mismatch. From http://www.debianadmin.com/remote-desktop-sharing-in-ubuntu.html I see it's using port 0, while standard vnc port is 5900 (and 5901 5902 etc).
Try to add :0 or :1 after the requested IP in your vnc client.