# Ubuntu 22.04 running via remote desktop has no desktop or taskbar

Tags: 22.04, panel, activities-overview

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04. I can only log in via remote desktop.

There is only an "activities" button and nothing else. There is no Desktop, no desktop icons, no task bar. The "appearance" section is also missing from settings.

I can not log in locally because this is a VM on a company's infrastructure. I don't know if this is normal for Ubuntu 22.04 or if this is because of the rdp.

When I want to switch windows I always have to go through this button. They're not minimized somewhere.

I found out that Xorg is being used.

Are there any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the ubuntu session instead of the default GNOME session.
In your home folder, create the file `.xsessionrc` with the following content

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Logout and Login.

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442514/how-to-login-to-the-ubuntu-not-gnome-session-on-a-remote-server-using-xrdp).