# Strange Problem in VINO, XUbuntu related to vnc password

Tags: networking, xubuntu, vnc

If I set the vncpassword, lets say: `trump123` in Xubuntu as following:

[`gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password $(echo -n 'trump123'|base64)`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112127/how-to-set-vinos-password-through-terminal)

then, surprisingly I can remotely access this Xubuntu using MULTIPLE set of vnc passwords: `trump123`, `trump1234`, `trump12345`..., though I have set only `trump123`

Could You Please tell me what must have gone wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: [Bug #625579: Vino has a password limit of 8 characters](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/625579)

Comment: this does not seem to answer, could you please clarify ?

Comment: The bug report says it ignores everything past the 8th character, so `trump123` plus anything will work.

Comment: @organic marble, thanks