# Remote desktop not working when screen goes blank after upgrade to 21.04

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, vnc, 21.04

I just upgraded a dual screen workstation from 20.10 to 21.04. I use this workstation via remote desktop very often.
After the distro upgrade, I noticed that the remote desktop connection interrupts when the workstation screen goes blank. When the screen is blank, no remote desktop connection is accepted by the workstation (no lock screen is enabled only the blank screen feature).
Moreover now only one of the two screen is shared remotely, while before the remote window contained both screens.

Question: is it a bug or is there a tweak somewhere restoring the original (20.10) behaviour?
Should I install a independent screen sharing server and not use the gnome default one?

Thanks in advance.

Note: In the login page I can choose among two window manager: Ubuntu (default) and Gnome Flashback.
With the latter the remote desktop sharing option is not even present.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue; I had multiple issues with Screen Sharing from macOS to my Ubuntu 21.04, none of which I had under 20.04:

- the screensharing disconnected when the remote session locked (eg after 5 minutes of inactivity) & I could not then log in again remotely
- my Ubuntu server no longer showed up in Bonjour on my Mac (I use [screensharingmenulet](https://apps.apple.com/nz/app/screensharingmenulet/id578078659?mt=12)).
- the performance was terrible; I'm on the same LAN as the server yet I could not drag a window around the screen at better than about 1fps.
- keys would randomly repeat 100 times eg I would be typing a word and suddenly it would look like I held one of the keys down for 30 seconds and got the auto-repeat

You probably won't be pleased to hear it, but I wiped my drive and downgraded to 20.04 LTS desktop (full install) which comes with Vino and which works beautifully with my macOS Screen Sharing. You just need to [disable encryption](https://askubuntu.com/a/463697/587941) to connect from a Mac's built-in Screen Sharing app. It otherwise works really well indeed.