# Cannot share desktop 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: mac, connection-sharing

I am trying to share my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS screen.  I am trying to access it using Chicken of the VNC from a mac.

I have turned on Screen Sharing on the Ubuntu computer via the settings and set a password.  Remote Login is also on.

When I try to connect to the computer via Chicken of the Sea, I get:
*Connection Terminated
Unknown authType 18*

I can ssh into the Ubuntu computer.

I have done:
*>> sudo gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false*

I have also tried setting up a tunnel via ssh which works for connecting to my Centos Machine:
*>> ssh -L5900:127.0.0.1:5900 xxx@IPaddress*

I have also tried using mac Screen Sharing following the directions at [Log into Ubuntu from my Mac over VNC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419399/log-into-ubuntu-from-my-mac-over-vnc)

When I do this I get:
*Connection failed to IPaddress: The software on the remote computer appears to be incompatible with this version of Screen Sharing.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try this: gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false

Answer (score 4):

Solved! *Don't use sudo!* Change gsettings for your own user, *not* for the root user.

***Without `sudo`***, type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

(In the question, ran that command as root by prefixing it with `sudo`.)